# Cannot run CMUSphinx program

Tags: cmusphinx

I have installed CMUSphinx using this blog([Here](http://tordwessman.blogspot.in/2012/01/cmu-sphinx-under-ubuntulinux.html)). I did all the steps correctly. But when I executed a sample program provided in the same blog([This program](https://sites.google.com/site/wessmansourcecode/pocket.example.tar.gz)). It shows me the following error

--------- ERRROR: ----------
Unable create vader.
Init failed...

I Don't know what to do. I am using Ubuntu 11.10/64bit. Is there any package I have not installed?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you didn't install the plugin correctly. Make sure that

- plugin file is installed in the gstreamer folder. The plugin so file should be placed either in /usr/lib/gstreamer folder or GST_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable needs to be properly set.
- gst-inspect shows the plugin. See the output of the gst-inspect to check if plugin is detected. Check GST_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable if it's not.
- dynamic linker is properly configured. Check that pocketsphinx library is installed in /usr/lib or that LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable is properly set to include the folder where pocketpshinx library is installed

See the gstreamer documentation and Linux linker documentation for more details.